# Getting a View to render an Image from a database using ASP.Net MVC 4 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been pulling what little hair i have left out all day trying to figure this out.

I have a personal web app that i have been putting together following various tutorials and it has come along rather nicely. The problem I am running into is when I click on an image that is linked to a strongly typed view the view bill display with basic html however I can not pull any info from the database to display on the page using @Model.CardID.

Here is some info in regards to the app.  It is basically and index of cards from a trading card game.  The Main page works perfectly and I can see all the info being pulled from the database including images. I have since linked the images and was at a point where clicking on the image will pull the identity from the database and append it to the url.  With no action this will just display the image by itself in a browser page. This is not what I want.

I want to be able to click on the image and using the data parsed from the database open a view that is tied to the url that the system generates and for the life of me I can not figure it out.

Here are the controllers actions, model and view info.

Using Statements for the Controller:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using MTG_Card_App.Domain.Abstract;
    using MTG_Card_App.Domain.Entities;
    using MTG_Card_App.WebUI.Models;
```

Actions in the controller: CardController.cs

```
    public FileContentResult GetImage(int cardId)
    {
        Card card = repository.Cards.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CardID == cardId);
    if (card != null)
    {
        return File(card.ImageData, card.ImageMimeType);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

    public ViewResult FullImage(int cardId)
    {
        Card card = repository.Cards.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CardID == cardId);
    {
        return View(cardId);
    } ...(other closing brackets removed)
```

Model Class: Card.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace MTG_Card_App.Domain.Entities
    {
    public class Card
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int CardID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Card Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string CardText { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Card Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Card color")]
        public string Color { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter only one Card Set")]
        public string Set { get; set; }

        public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }

        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Summary Page (this is the index of cards) CardSummary.cshtml

```
    @model MTG_Card_App.Domain.Entities.Card

    <div class="item">

        @if (Model.ImageData != null)
        {
            <div>
                <a href="@Url.Action("FullImage", "Card", new { Model.CardID })">
                <img width="105" height="150" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Card",
                new { Model.CardID })" />
                </a>
            </div>

        }

        <h2>@Model.Name</h2>
        <p>@Model.CardText</p>
        <h3>@Model.Type</h3>
        <h3>@Model.Color</h3>
        <p>@Model.Set</p>

    </div>
```

The @URL.Action helpers work correctly on this page and display the images from the database correctly. And when hovering over the image i am getting the url to show as localhost:*****/Card/FullImage?CardID=1 and so on for each image in the CardSumnmary page.  When I click the image I can get the FullImage view to load but can not get the image generate.

Here is the code for the FullImage.cshtml

```
    @model MTG_Card_App.Domain.Entities.Card

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "FullImage";
    }
    <h2>Full Image</h2>
    <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Card", new { @Model.CardID })" />
```

I have just updated all of this info and ran the app and received a new error message that I have not gotten before:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'MTG_Card_App.Domain.Entities.Card'.

Any Assistance on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for any answers or info that can point me in the right direction.

Please let me know if there are any other files you may need to view.

Comment: The error message you see is because you're passing `return View(cardId)` but your FullImage view declares it expects a `@model Card`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It fixed the error and it is now working 100%.  If you want to put that as an answer I would be more then willing to accept it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from this code:

```
public ViewResult FullImage(int cardId)
{
    Card card = repository.Cards.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CardID == cardId);
{
    return View(cardId); // throws InvalidOperationException
} ...(other closing brackets removed)
```

Instead of returning `Card` model class from controller to your view, you're trying to return `cardId` which has `int` type, hence throws `InvalidOperationException`. Change return model to `card` and it works fine:

```
public ViewResult FullImage(int cardId)
{
    Card card = repository.Cards.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CardID == cardId);
{
    return View(card); // returning model class, not a passed property id
} ...(other closing brackets removed)
```